# OpenCv Face Recognition issue

Tags: python, image, opencv, face-recognition

I am getting an error in OpenCv -

`cv2.face has no attribute create LBPHFaceRecognizer`

I already installed OpenCv contrib Python

Python version 3.6

OpenCv version 3.4

Comment: I'm sorry, but as it stands this post makes absolutely no sense. Please, rewrite it to include a clear problem statement, a well formatted [mcve], and anything else necessary to unambiguously convey what you want to solve.

Comment: You need to add some context so we can understand, what's your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found is based on Opencv 3.2, but I guess it should still be valid.

The function you need to use is `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`.
(https://www.superdatascience.com/opencv-face-recognition/)

Since there is no code provided, that is all I can tell you right now.